# Javascript, Quirks of using undefined variables

Tags: javascript, variables, undefined

This is gonna be a bit of a weird one b/c I can't provide the actual input for the test case. On the codingGame website there is an exercise where I have to find the lowest difference between integers. I create a variable, but leave it undefined and later use it to hold the lowest difference

```
function shortest(horses){
  let short;
  horses.sort((a,b) => a - b).forEach((horse,i) => {
    let dif = horse - horses[i-1];
    if (dif < short || !short) short = dif; 
  });
  return short;
};
```

This passes all the tests but one, and the only way to solve the failed one is to assign a value to short instead of leaving it undefined (like let short = 10000000000000);
The website, annoyingly, won't give out the input so I'm not sure why the code is behaving this way so does does anyone know why leaving it undefined instead of a value will cause problems?

Comment: You are testing it like it's a number `if (dif < short` - so it does need a numeric default, setting it to a high default number sounds reasonable

Comment: Is it possible for any difference to be 0?

Comment: Also it appears that questions without a [example] (including input) is off topic https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/359867/5267751 (which also means this one can't be fixed)

Comment: You could reverse the condition `if (!short || …` since the `||` will short-circuit.

Comment: Think about what would happen if `horses` is an empty array - what would be the result of `short` then? Would it be different and how, if you had assigned a value to it vs not assigning a value?